# Take portion of MIT license library, and redistribute in new library

Tags: license-compatibility, mit, redistribution

I am currently writing a java library that I intend to release under MIT license.

Right now I have drawn on another MIT license library.

I would like to only use a couple source files/classes from the other library in my library. I would like to just embed those source file directly in my library and modify them as I see fit to meet my needs.

Is this compliant with MIT license? What do I need to add to my GitHub page when I publish it, in regards to the portions of the other library that I embedded in my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the MIT License:

> Copyright [YEAR] [COPYRIGHT HOLDER]
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So - you can redistribute modified versions of specific classes from an MIT-licensed project. You'll have to keep the original copyright and license for them, though.

An acceptable approach could be to have such a paragraph in your license (or readme) file:

> Classes under the XYZ package were taken from project ABC, Copyright 1999 Original Author.
>   These classes are licensed under the MIT license. See XYZ-LICENSE.md for additional details.